# Emberjs outlet inside a component

Tags: ember.js

It is possible to have an `{{outlet}}` helper inside a component ?

With a router like this  :

```
Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('pages', function(){
        this.resource( 'page', { path: '/:id' }, function(){
            this.route('edit');

        });
    });
});
```

I'm using my component as pages, and it display a list of page. I have set a `{{link-to}}` to each page to render the page template inside my component. (Page template is not a component)

Is it possible ? because it's not doing anything, so far my app is routing to `/pages/page_id` but the nested template is not display inside my component.

Is outlet not working within a component ?

Thanks for the help.

[EDIT] Here is a small example of what it looks like :

Component :

```
<div class="nestedTemplate">
{{outlet}}
</div>

<div>
{{#each item in model}}
    {{partial "list-row"}}
{{else}}
    {{partial "no-items"}} 
{{/each}}
</div>
```

The partial is just the list formatted correctly. with a `{{link-to}}` around each div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, is not possible. You can either pass property values to the component or use the `{{yield}}` helper. See: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_yield

Comment: That's too bad for my case, but I guess I can understand. I knew that we could pass properties already, but I thought we could specified a component as a target to be render from renderTemplate. :)